# How do I make the cue ball move to the heading given?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Been using turtle library to make a billiard and cue ball trajectory. I have implemented the ball trajectory physics, so when it hits the walls (or limited distance specified) it reflects to the appropriate direction. But I faced a problem where the ball goes to a direction I didn't specify then according to the heading given it rotates a bit to that direction. I debugged the code and found no issues, and tried to find where the coordinates the cue ball is trying to initially go to, knowing that if the loop of ball movement changes, the initial value always is to go to that direction and breaks the point of having a heading.

```
import turtle
from math import *

t = turtle.Turtle()
width=200

# White ball - Moving ball
t.color("black")
t.shape("circle")
t.penup()
t.goto(90,-80)

# White ball - Permanent
ball=turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.penup()
ball.goto(90,-80)
ball.color("black")
ball.shape("circle")

angleString="Enter the hit force's angle (0-360) in degrees: "

angle=int(input(angleString))

# Moving Ball
t.color("yellow")

# Ball movement mechanic
step=20
t.penup()
LIMIT_X=width-8
LIMIT_Y=(width/2)-8
t.setheading(angle)
t.pendown()

x=-LIMIT_X
y=LIMIT_Y
t.dx=step*cos(angle)
t.dy=step*sin(angle)

for x in range(50):
  t.speed(1)
  print(x,t.pos(), t.heading())
  x+=t.dx
  y+=t.dy
  t.goto(x,y)

  # Check vertical borders
  if abs(x)>LIMIT_X:
    t.dx=-t.dx
    
  # Check horizontal borders
  if abs(y)>LIMIT_Y:
    t.dy=-t.dy

turtle.done()
```

[showcasing an example of angle 120](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0OC9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.  First, you have two different `x` variables in play at the same time:

```
x=-LIMIT_X
y=LIMIT_Y
t.dx=step*cos(angle)
t.dy=step*sin(angle)

for x in range(50):
  t.speed(1)
  print(x,t.pos(), t.heading())
  x+=t.dx
  y+=t.dy
  t.goto(x,y)
```

I'm guessing the iteration `x` variable is only meant for the debugging `print()` statement, not to position the ball, and should be renamed.

Second, `angle` is in *degrees* but the trigonometric funtions from the **math** module assume *radians*, so these calculations make no sense:

```
t.dx=step*cos(angle)
t.dy=step*sin(angle)
```

Use the `radians()` function from **math** to convert the angle.  (Turtle can work with either, but you need to tell it if you want to use radians instead of degrees.)

Additionally, this statement does nothing:

```
t.setheading(angle)
```

as you move your ball with `goto()`.  The heading would only matter if you were moving your ball with `forward()`.

My rework of your code fixing the above along with other changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sin, cos, radians

WIDTH = 200
LIMIT_X = WIDTH - 8
LIMIT_Y = WIDTH/2 - 8

STEP = 20

ANGLE_STRING = "Enter the hit force's angle (0-360) in degrees: "

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

angle = int(input(ANGLE_STRING))

screen = Screen()

# Billard table (roughly)
table = Turtle()
table.hideturtle()
table.shape('square')
table.shapesize(WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE + 1, WIDTH*2 / CURSOR_SIZE + 1)
table.color('green')
table.stamp()

# Black ball - Permanent
permanent = Turtle()
permanent.shape('circle')
permanent.color('black')
permanent.penup()
permanent.goto(90, -80)

# Yellow ball - Moving ball
moving = permanent.clone()
moving.color('yellow')
moving.pendown()

x = -LIMIT_X
y = LIMIT_Y
moving.dx = STEP * cos(radians(angle))
moving.dy = STEP * sin(radians(angle))

for z in range(50):
    moving.speed('slowest')
    print(z, moving.pos(), moving.heading())

    x += moving.dx
    y += moving.dy
    moving.goto(x, y)

    # Check vertical borders
    if abs(x) > LIMIT_X:
        moving.dx = -moving.dx

    # Check horizontal borders
    if abs(y) > LIMIT_Y:
        moving.dy = -moving.dy

screen.mainloop()
```

I'm not saying it does what you want, it's simply less buggy.  Perhaps basing your motion on `setheading()` and `forward()` instead of `goto()` might get you the result you desire.  You'll have to rethink your wall reflection logic, of course.